# Convert flattened data frame to struct in Spark

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I had a deep nested `JSON` files which I had to process, and in order to do that I had to flatten them because couldn't find a way to hash some deep nested fields. This is how my `dataframe` looks like (after flattening):

```
scala> flattendedJSON.printSchema
root
 |-- header_appID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- header_appVersion: string (nullable = true)
 |-- header_userID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- body_cardId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- body_cardStatus: string (nullable = true)
 |-- body_cardType: string (nullable = true)
 |-- header_userAgent_browser: string (nullable = true)
 |-- header_userAgent_browserVersion: string (nullable = true)
 |-- header_userAgent_deviceName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- body_beneficiary_beneficiaryAccounts_beneficiaryAccountOwner: string (nullable = true)
 |-- body_beneficiary_beneficiaryPhoneNumbers_beneficiaryPhoneNumber: string (nullable = true)
```

And I need to convert it back to original structure (before flattening):

```
scala> nestedJson.printSchema
root
 |-- header: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- appID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- appVersion: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- userAgent: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- browser: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- browserVersion: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- deviceName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- body: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- beneficiary: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- beneficiaryAccounts: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- beneficiaryAccountOwner: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- beneficiaryPhoneNumbers: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- beneficiaryPhoneNumber: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- cardId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- cardStatus: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- cardType: string (nullable = true)
```

I've managed to do it with single nested field, but if it's more, it can't work and I can't find a way to do it properly. Here's what I tried:

```
 val structColumns = flattendedJSON.columns.filter(_.contains("_"))
  val structColumnsMap = structColumns.map(_.split("\\_")).
  groupBy(_(0)).mapValues(_.map(_(1)))

  val dfExpanded = structColumnsMap.foldLeft(flattendedJSON){ (accDF, kv) =>
  val cols = kv._2.map(v => col("`" + kv._1 + "_" + v + "`").as(v))
  accDF.withColumn(kv._1, struct(cols: _*))
}
val dfResult = structColumns.foldLeft(flattendedJSON)(_ drop _)
```

And it's working if I have one nested object (e.g. `header_appID`), but in case of `header_userAgent_browser`, I get an exception:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve
>   '`header_userAgent`' given input columns: ..

Using `Spark 2.3` and `Scala 2.11.8`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend use `case classes` to work with a `Dataset` instead of flatten the `DF` and then again try to convert to the old `json` format. Even if it has nested objects you can define a set of `case classes` to cast it. It allows you to work with an object notation making the things easier than `DF`.
There are tools where you can provide a sample of the `json` and it generates the classes for you (I use this: https://json2caseclass.cleverapps.io). 
If you anyways want to convert it from the `DF`, an alternative could be, create a `Dataset` using `map` on your `DF`. Something like this:

```
case class NestedNode(fieldC: String, fieldD: String)   // for JSON
case class MainNode(fieldA: String, fieldB: NestedNode) // for JSON
case class FlattenData(fa: String, fc: String, fd: String) 

Seq(
  FlattenData("A1", "B1", "C1"),
  FlattenData("A2", "B2", "C2"),
  FlattenData("A3", "B3", "C3")
).toDF
 .as[FlattenData] // Cast it to access with object notation
 .map(flattenItem=>{
    MainNode(flattenItem.fa, NestedNode(flattenItem.fc, flattenItem.fd) ) // Creating output format
  })
```

At the end, that schema defined with the classes will be used by `yourDS.write.mode(your_save_mode).json(your_target_path)`

Comment: I gave up, and used jackson to parse deep nested jsons with JsonNode. It was quite fast and reliable for 1 year of events stored in Cassandra table